# console application c# roundoff

Tags: c#

whats wrong with my code 
it suppose to be
if i enter 98 it will become 100
if i enter 99 it will become also 100
if i enter 97 it will still be 97
and also i will ask the user first how many grade i will enter.
its just all about road off .
tnx .
i hope you all understand what im saying. 
tnx im not good in english sorry.

```
    class uno
    {
    private int grade;
    public void setgrade(int Mygrade)
     {
    grade = Mygrade;

     }
    public void evaluate()
    {
        if (grade < 45 && grade > 40)
        {
            int inden;
            inden = 45 - grade;
            if (inden > 3)
            {

                grade = 45;
            }

        }
        else if (grade < 50 && grade > 45)
        {
            int inden;
            inden = 50 - grade;
            if (inden > 3)
            {
                grade = 50;

            }

        }

        else if (grade < 55 && grade > 50)
        {

            int inden;
            inden = 55 - grade;
            if (inden > 3) 
            {
                grade = 55;
            }
        }
        else if (grade < 60 && grade > 55)
        {

            int inden;
            inden = 60 - grade;
            if (inden > 3)
            {
                grade = 60;
            }
        }
        else if (grade < 65 && grade > 60)
        {

            int inden;
            inden = 65 - grade;
            if (inden > 3)
            {
                grade = 65;
            }
        }


        else if (grade < 70 && grade > 65)
        {

            int inden;
            inden = 70 - grade;
            if (inden > 3)
            {
                grade = 70;
            }
        }
        else if (grade < 75 && grade > 70)
        {

            int inden;
            inden = 75 - grade;
            if (inden > 3)
            {
                grade = 75;
            }
        }
        else if (grade < 80 && grade > 75)
        {

            int inden;
            inden = 80 - grade;
            if (inden > 3)
            {
                grade = 80;
            }
        }

        else if (grade < 85 && grade > 75)
        {

            int inden;
            inden = 85 - grade;
            if (inden > 3)
            {
                grade = 85;
            }
        }
        else if (grade < 90 && grade > 85)
        {

            int inden;
            inden = 90 - grade;
            if (inden > 3)
            {
                grade = 90;
            }
        }
        else if (grade < 95 && grade > 90)
        {

            int inden;
            inden = 95 - grade;
            if (inden > 3)
            {
                grade = 95;
            }
        }
        else if (grade < 100 && grade > 95)
        {

            int inden;
            inden = 100 - grade;
            if (inden > 3)
            {
                grade = 100;
            }
        }
        else
        { 


        }

    }
    public int getit()
    {
        return grade;
    }

}


    class Program
     {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        uno a = new uno();
        Console.WriteLine("enter grade");

        int Grade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (Grade > 100 || Grade < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("invalid input");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }
        a.setgrade(Grade);


        a.evaluate();
        switch (a.getit())
        { 
            case 45:
                Console.WriteLine(45);
                break;

            case 50:
                Console.WriteLine(50);
                break;

            case 55:
                Console.WriteLine(55);
                break;

            case 60:
                Console.WriteLine(60);
                break;

            case 65:
                Console.WriteLine(65);
                break;

            case 70:
                Console.WriteLine(70);
                break;

            case 75:
                Console.WriteLine(75);
                break;

            case 80:
                Console.WriteLine(80);
                break;

            case 85:
                Console.WriteLine(85);
                break;

            case 90:
                Console.WriteLine(90);
                break;

            case 95:
                Console.WriteLine(95);
                break;

            case 100:
                Console.WriteLine(100);
                break;

        }


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
     }
```

Comment: What does your code do wrong? How are you calling it?

Comment: @van. I can see where you going wrong. But instead of giving you the answer I will give you my 2 cents advise that will help you in long run. Put a breakpoint here " if (Grade > 100 || Grade < 0)" and debug, you will soon find out whats happening.

Comment: i dont know why its not going inside the switch maybe because of my evaluate() its wrong?

Comment: Why not do `Console.WriteLine(a.getit());` rather than that big `switch` statement?

Comment: how can i make this like it will ask first how many grades i will input then if i enter all the grades it will roand off .example how many grades youwill input 4 then i input 45 54 34 54 then it will round off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
class Uno
{
    public int Grade { get; set; }

    public void Evaluate()
    {
        if (this.Grade >= 45)
        {
            if ((this.Grade % 5) > 2)
            {
                this.Grade += 5 - (this.Grade % 5);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uno a = new Uno();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter grades. Enter one per line. Enter a blank line to stop.");

        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        while (input != "")
        {
            int grade = int.Parse(input);
            if (grade > 100 || grade < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Try again.");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                continue;
            }
            a.Grade = grade;
            a.Evaluate();
            Console.WriteLine(a.Grade);
            input = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I've refactored your code and set all the naming conventions to normal C# coding standards.

Comment: @Ivan - It should be working fine. I tested it before posting. If you have `this. Grade + = 5 - (this.Grade % 5);` then it won't. It must be `this.Grade += 5 - (this.Grade % 5);`.